# How do you add your app to the contacts share menu?

Tags: android, contacts

I'm looking to add my app to the popup menu that appears when you choose to a share a contact from the phone contacts app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/x-vCard"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#mime "MIME type matching in the Android framework is case-sensitive, unlike formal RFC MIME types. As a result, you should always specify MIME types using lowercase letters."
so x-vCard is not required I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register an intent filter in our manifest.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Try this:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact" android:host="com.android.contacts"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: This adds the app to a popup when i select a contact.  I'm trying to add it to the popup when i share a contact.